# MAX date value within a range with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, max

To make it easy

```
+---+----+-------------+
|   | A  |      B      |
+---+----+-------------+
| 1 | xx | 12-05-2015  |
| 2 | xx | 15-05-2015  |
| 3 | yy | 13-05-2015  |
| 4 | yy | 16-05-2015  |
+---+----+-------------+
```

(today is 14-05-2015)

I need to get the MAX date value for each "A" value only if it is before today.
In case it's not, move to the 2nd biggest value. Case it does not find, empty cell.

What I've done so far:

```
=MAX($A$1:$A$4='xx';$B$1:$B$4<TODAY();$B$1:$B$4)
```

and confirm with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The error I get is that it yields 13-05-2015 as max value for xx, which is obviously wrong (as if it does not take into account the `$A$1:$A$4='xx'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use nested if-functions. I.e. change your formula into:

```
{=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$4="xx", IF($B$1:$B$4<TODAY(), $B$1:$B$4)))}
```

And end it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

A standard (*non-array*) formula alternative.

```
=MAX(INDEX((B:B)*(A:A="xx")*(B:B<TODAY()), , ))
```

[image: MAX Date If Conditions]

This formula would benefits from having its cell ranges cut down from full columns to something closer to the usable data range.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are sorted ascending as shown in the example then you can use `LOOKUP` like this:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A$100="xx")/(B$1:B$100<TODAY()),B$1:B$100)`

Doesn't require "array entry"